# Очередь к базе данных

Tags: база-данных, многопоточность, ruby

Задача такова
Приходит большой массив данных в формате JSON
Их него надо выбрать несколько полей и сохранить их в базу данных.
Проблема в том, что таких массивов данных очень много, обработка одного занимает приличное время.

Хотелось бы организовать следующую систему.

```
 http-parser->| Queue |->{Worker_1}->{DB}
              | Item1 |  {Worker_2}
              | Item2 |  {Worker_n}
              | ItemN |
```

Небольшой скрипт на Ruby получает ответ от сервера, добавляет его в очередь и продолжает и ждет следующего ответа от сервера. В свою очередь воркеры, если видят информацию в очереди, то они разбирают её и начинают обрабатывать и сохранять в базу данных.

На данный момент сложность в том, что парсер отвечает за все: парсинг, выборку, сохранение в БД, поэтому обработка ответов от сервера сильно затягивается.

Нулевая мысль была банально бросать сохранение в БД в отдельный тред, однако это не очень гибкое решение.

Первая же мысль была банально забрасывать весь json объект прямо в базу, а потом тягать оттуда, но тогда стоит вопрос о том, как блокировать запись, чтобы worker_n не стал обрабатывать одну и ту же запись вместе с другим воркером.

Другими словами интересуют известные методы\ПО, позволяющее сократить время записи в БД. В частности интересуют какие-нибудь продукты Amazon Web Services. Я вскользь прочитал про Amazon Simple Queue, но не уверен, что она покроет мои задачи.

Comment: А ваша БД позволяет давать записям ID без разрывов в нумерации. Вы можете без блокировок сделать, что бы воркер N обрабатывал только каждую M запись (кол-во воркеров) с постоянным смещением N

Comment: Кстати, идея здравая! Спасибо большое. Есть какие-нибудь идеи, как уведомлять workerов и какие способы их уведомления вообще существуют. Мне пока что в голову только приходят Rails.

Answer (score 2):

Способов, вообще говоря,  полно.

Можно использовать Amazon SQS, верно. [Пример использования](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/aws-sdk-v1/samples/sqs/add_queue_message.rb) выглядит несложно. Но это облачный сервис, что многие для такой (вроде) простой задачи сочтут "пушкой по воробьям", хотя вы сами поинтересовались именно ими.

Можно использовать свой сервер обмена сообщениями с подтверждением доставки, их есть много, но для примера, есть RabbitMQ.

Можно использовать PostgreSQL и его фичу "advisory lock", блокировку, о смысле которой знает только приложение, сама СУБД не обращает на неё внимания. Такой подход использует [очередь Que](https://github.com/chanks/que), в которой уже реализована SQL-часть. В этом подходе приятно то, что управлять задачами можно в транзакциях с ACID вместе с изменением других данных.

---

**А теперь плохие идеи.**

Можно использовать `Concurrent::Edge::Channel` из `concurrent-ruby`. А в задачах, где большая часть состоит из активного Ruby, а не ввода/вывода, это **плохая идея**, потому что в MRI есть GIL, из-за которого будет выполняться **только одна** задача в каждый момент времени.

Можно выполнять каждым воркером каждую N-ую задачу из БД, как предложено в комментариях. Но это будет хорошо работать только если все задачи примерно одинаково трудоёмки (иначе некоторые воркеры будут отставать от остальных) и все воркеры никогда не падают (т. к. каждая N-ая задача может быть выполнена ровно одним воркером).

Answer (score 1):

> На данный момент сложность в том, что парсер отвечает за все: парсинг, выборку, сохранение в БД, поэтому обработка ответов от сервера сильно затягивается.

Поздравляю. Это называется [God-object](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82). И от него в любом случае следует избавиться.

Что же касается основной задачи - вариант "в лоб" это сохранять данные в файл и в отдельном процессе их разбирать.
На самом деле, есть более изящные решения, например тот же [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Работает это так:
Тебе нужно создать класс, который будет содержать публичный метод `perform` и примешать к нему `Sidekiq::Worker`.

Т.е. получится что-то типа такого:

```
class DelayedParser
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(json)
    # тут что-то делаешь с данными
  end
end
DelayedParser.perform_async(json) # json - данные которые нужно обрабатывать.
```